# How do i write the function for ‘I’ should be less than 20% of ‘H’

Tags: excel, excel-formula

So i know this needs to be done through conditional formatting i am guessing, just don't know how to write the function.

‘I’ should be less than 20% of ‘H’, if true then i need the cell to be green, if false, red.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you need something like:

```
=if(I<(H*0.2),1,0)
```

and if the result is 1 then format as green, otherwise red...

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad I think I was just trying to explain the logic as well.